# My adviser will be out of the town during the semester when I'm planning to defend

Tags: thesis, masters, defense

Originally I was planning to defend my thesis during spring semester, however my adviser suggested me to delay my defense to the summer semester. He motivated this by the fact that my thesis writing need more work, even though my research results are good and ready.

After I declined Spring graduation, he told me that during the Summer semester he won't be at the University, which I didn't like, because, first of all, he didn't warn me about this in advance (even, as I know, he knew that he is going to another state during summer before delaying my thesis defense), and also this means that my professor doesn't care much about me and my defense, and that I have to delay my defense again to the Winter Semester, which I don't like either, since I think I'm ready to defend in Summer.

Because my adviser is a thesis committee chair, I can't defend without him, even if other committee members will be able to attend my defense. At the same time I don't think that changing my adviser is a good idea, because we were working together for the past two years, he knows me and my research very well, and also there is no other professors at the department that have similar research interests.

So, I see another delaying of my graduation as the only option, which is very frustrating for me. I would appreciate any advice on this situation, and in particular, how to speed up my defense.

Comment: Literally just-a-comment: I would agree that either your advisor doesn't care much about your project, thesis, and defense, or your advisor is stunningly clue-less. The latter is sadly too-often possible. Either way, it is clear that your advisor is not thinking in terms of taking care of you, so you should consider the situation that "it's left up to you" to take care of yourself.

Comment: In the 21st century, someone being out of town should not be a reason to not hold a thesis defense. Tell him that it's important for you to defend your thesis during the summer semester, and ask if he could participate via Skype. I expect that that will solve the problem.

Comment: Or, couldn't he simply return to the campus for the defense?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @DanRomik, I agree that this is, probably, the best option, however one thing confuses me: I never seen a defense where chair of thesis committee is not physically present.

Comment: I've had my own students defend with one of four committee members present only via "Skype", which came-and-went as the train went through various tunnels somewhere in France. And some other more recent similar episodes. What I'd worry is more that "physical absence" is a sort of fake excuse/rationalization for irresponsibility or disconnect.

Comment: My father defended his dissertation over the phone in the 70s, and I defended my masters thesis on the phone in the 00s. It's not ideal (or is it? if *you're* the one out of town you can do it in your pajamas...while sipping a drink...while laying in bed...not that I have *any* personal experience with that haha), but it's certainly done.

Comment: I have been at a PhD defense where the chair was in another country. So, what is the question again?

Comment: I think you're jumping to conclusions about your advisor (unless there's more that you haven't told us). // Two years is very, very quick work. // Do you have something else lined up that you wanted to get started with over the summer?  If not, just schedule your defense for a date at the end of the summer.  Use the summer to polish up the writing, collaborating remotely, and to apply for the next chapter of your career.  You can also get started with a new project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)  agree with others that this is the 21st century.  committee members (chair or not) should be able to skype in to a defense.  this is common practice at all 3 universities i've been associated with.

2)  there should be a graduate advisor type person in your department or college with whom you can consult.  this person is likely someone who helps with recruitment, ensuring students are properly registered for courses and comprehensive/qualifying exams, helping students navigate the "rules" of defending, etc.  talk to this person and explain the situation.  they will likely be able to help you with #1.